# Issue running Scene Kit's presentation WWDC2013 code

Tags: ios, scenekit, nsview, wwdc

I am trying to run the [source code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SceneKit_Slides_WWDC2013/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013423) from Apple's Scene Kit presentation from WWDC2013. I am getting an error and not sure how to resolve.

Here is the error I am getting:

**ASCSlideNodeDelegate.m:238:94: Type of property 'view' ('NSView * _Nonnull') does not match type of accessor 'view' ('SCNView *')**

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the `SCNView` in ASCPresentationViewController needs to be changed to match new SDK headers.

In the ASCPresentationViewController.h, switch from a method declaration for the -view superclass override to a property in the header, and specify @dynamic for that property in ASCPresentationViewController.m.

```
@property (strong) SCNView *view;
//- (SCNView *)view;

@dynamic view;
//- (SCNView *)view {
//    return (SCNView *)[super view];
//}
```

You can find diffs for some other needed updates at [Updating SceneKit WWDC 2013 slides for Xcode 7](https://halmueller.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/updating-scenekit-wwdc-2013-slides-for-xcode-7/) (my Wordpress blog).

Comment: Thanks for the help!, Just changing the definition of SCNView in ASCPresentationViewController.h and switching the method declaration in ASCPresentationViewController.m worked for me :)